# Does Apple's Remote Desktop need OSX Server?

Tags: remote-desktop, mac, mac-osx-server, apple

Does Apple's Remote Desktop need OSX Server? Or are there better management options out there? I'm looking for something to manage a small Mac lab of ~20 machines joined to Active Directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check out the website for ARD for the answer.](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) You just need to install it on a Mac. Server not required.

Another option is [Netopia's Timbuktu](http://www.netopia.com/software/products/tb2/) or any [VNC viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) to connect to the VNC server that OS X has built in. Check out [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) for Mac.